# How to count the number of occurrences in a table through filtering in summarise in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, count, data-cleaning

I have a data frame like this:

```
    df <- data.frame(Identifier = c("A","B","C"), 
          Year = c("2020","2020","2019"), Sex = c("Male","Male","Female")
```

I want to then filter this, and count the number of each sex. I thought this would work with n() but:

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>% summarise(Number_males = n(Sex =="Male"))
```

Does not work. I would like the following output:

```
  Year Number_males
1 2020   2
2 2019   0
```

Note: my real data frame is considerably more complicated than this one, and so I cannot afford to just filter by Gender == Male separately

Answer (score 1):

We need to `sum` the logical vector  as `TRUE` -> 1 and `FALSE` -> 0

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Year) %>%
   summarise(Number_males = sum(Sex =="Male"))
```